# schema.org: which language to use for markup

Tags: metadata, schema.org

This may sound like a stupid question, but: which language should I use for my code markup? I'm writing articles in German language.

Of course the tags themselves are fixed, but how to help bots understand the topic I'm writing about?

`<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MedicalWebPage">
<link itemprop="about" href="http://schema.org/MedicalCondition" />
<meta itemprop="name" content="Posttraumatische Belastungsstörung"/>
<meta itemprop="aspect" content="Psychotherapie"/>
<meta itemprop="keywords" content="Trauma, PITT, PTBS, PTSD, Traumatherapie"/>
<meta itemprop="alternateName" content="PTBS"/>`

The following questions arise:

1. Can I add a few 'aspects' within a single property or do I have to
   add 1 'aspect' tag for each?
2. would it be better to use the English terms for categorizing properties such as 'aspect' or 'keywords', like using
   'psychotherapy' or 'diagnosis' instead of 'Psychotherapie' and
   'Diagnose'?
3. of course I'd like to avoid bloating my html code. Does it even make sense to define another 'keywords' tag if I have the respective
   regular meta tag in my document anyway?

Comment: I think your questions 1 and 3 are not closely enough related to be in the same post; ideally you would [edit] them out and create separate question posts for these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious way is to use the language the content/document is in. This becomes clear if you think of, for example, a [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting): its `name` should of course be the actual blog posting title, not a translation of it; even more so the [`articleBody`](http://schema.org/articleBody). In general, this is the case for properties like `aspect` and `keywords`, too. However, in some cases Schema.org might decide to recommend to use certain values (so not just giving examples, like they do for `aspect`)¹, in which case you should follow this advice instead of translating the values.

Having said that, there could of course be consumers that *do something* with German content but expect certain properties with certain values (in a certain other language) for that purpose. Unless you know about such a consumer, I wouldn’t worry about it.

You could provide values in multiple languages if you think it’s useful. In Microdata, parsers wouldn’t differentiate between the languages (as Microdata doesn’t care about HTML’s `lang` attribute, so it’s not very practical), but it’s [possible with RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-html-rdfa-20150317/#specifying-the-language-for-a-literal).

¹ In such a case, they should ideally use enumeration URIs, as they are language-independent; e.g., for [`MedicalSpecialty`](http://schema.org/MedicalSpecialty): [`http://schema.org/Psychiatric`](http://schema.org/Psychiatric), [`http://schema.org/PlasticSurgery`](http://schema.org/PlasticSurgery) etc.